# What is this conditional probability?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have been doing some reading for a project on quantitive finance, and I have been seeing a lot of this kind of conditional probabilities on a "$\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$":

$$\mathbb{P} [C(t_{i+1})<y|\mathcal{F}_{t_i}]=\mathbb{P} [C(t_{i+1})<y|C(t_i)]$$

I have no problem understanding the second probability. The C is a portfolio value by the way.The problem is the $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$, I want to know what it stands for. I know this is probably a stupid question, but I don't know where to look exactly.

Comment: Shouldn't $\mathcal{F}_t$ (a $\sigma-$ algebra) stand for the informations available on the market at time t?. I think the step you indicated is justified by the Markov Property. In general you can think of a $\sigma-$algebra as a set containing all the informations you know, especially in finance.

Comment: Exactly, that's the Markov property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$ is a member of a filtration which is a set of $\sigma$ algebras indexed by time.  To be measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}_{t_i}$ means to only depend on the information available up to and including time $t_i$.  Conditioning probability on it means given the information available up to and including $t_i$, what is the probability.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathscr{F}_{t_i}$ represents a sigma algebra, which is a fancy term for "available information". In this case your only available information for computing the probability is the portfolio value $C(t_i)$.